# Pattern matching without case classes

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, case-class

Is it possible, through pattern matching, to detect the subtype of a class that is not a case class?

I need to use existing Java classes, so I can't declare my own case classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep!  You can pattern match on type, so if you have different cases for different subtypes, you can get the behavior you're looking for:

```
trait A
class B extends A
class C extends A

def f(a: A) = a match {
  case b: B => "a B!"
  case c: C => "a C!" 
}

f(new B)  // a B!
f(new C)  // a C!
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks! Thanks to you I found it's called "type matching", or typecase - there's more information [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/bqbase/2006/10/11/typecase.html)

Comment: Also, it's worth knowing `A` can be `Object` (or `Any`)